# Duplicar registros a excepcion de una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas a todos, estoy tratando de duplicar estos 3 registros a otro usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que consigue el resultado de la imagen.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (IDSOL INT not null PRIMARY KEY ,USUARIO VARCHAR(50) ,LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,FirstName varchar(255),Age int, )

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(1,'ADMIN','RODRIGUEZ','LOPEZ',20)
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(2,'ADMIN','YAÑEZ','CARROL',20)
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(3,'ADMIN','MONS','JAFET',20)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP


--DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Trate de duplicarlo tal cual con un usuario diferente solo que la columna IDSOL es PRIMARY KEY por lo cual no se pueden repetir el mismo valor, alguno me podria dar una idea ?, estaba pensando usar un WHILE e insertar registro por registro pero a un no tengo la idea clara.

Comment: Consulta, porque queres hacer que el id sea igual en los otros registros? No haría falta, tranquilamente esos ids deberían ser 4,5,6 y tampoco hace falta insertarlos ya que son identity y se auto generan.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, modifique la pregunta la columna no es identity solo es primary key

Comment: y porque no crear IDSOL como autoincrementable?, con eso te ahorras duplicar ese valor y obtener siempre el siguiente. Si el ultimo es 3, deberias obtener 4, 5, y 6 como te dicen arriba!

Comment: No tengo permitido modificar la tabla con la que trabajo :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lo ideal.

La definición de tu tabla debe ser un [`IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) para `IDSOL` que es tu llave primaria, de esta forma solo tendrás que hacer un simple `INSERT` a partir de un `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (IDSOL INT not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,USUARIO VARCHAR(50) ,LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,FirstName varchar(255),Age int, )

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('ADMIN','RODRIGUEZ','LOPEZ',20) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('ADMIN','YAÑEZ','CARROL',20)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('ADMIN','MONS','JAFET',20)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'USUARIO', LastName, FirstName, Age FROM #TEMP GROUP BY IDSOL, LastName, FirstName, Age

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

El resutlado será el siguiente:

```
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|   | IDSOL | USUARIO | LastName  | FirstName | Age |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 1 | 1     | ADMIN   | RODRIGUEZ | LOPEZ     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 2 | 2     | ADMIN   | YAÑEZ     | CARROL    | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 3 | 3     | ADMIN   | MONS      | JAFET     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 4 | 4     | USUARIO | RODRIGUEZ | LOPEZ     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 5 | 5     | USUARIO | YAÑEZ     | CARROL    | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 6 | 6     | USUARIO | MONS      | JAFET     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

Aquí puedes ver [la demostración y sus resultados](http://rextester.com/PPL11503).

## Lo inevitable.

Si por alguna razón te es imposible modificar  la estructura de tu tabla temporal, una opción es calcular el último `IDSOL` insertado sumándole el número de registro con la función [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql), donde simplemente usas el mismo código que tú tienes y el `INSERT` es a través de un `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT (SELECT MAX(IDSOL) FROM #TEMP) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by IDSOL), 'USUARIO', LastName, FirstName, Age
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY IDSOL, LastName, FirstName, Age
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|   | IDSOL | USUARIO | LastName  | FirstName | Age |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 1 | 1     | ADMIN   | RODRIGUEZ | LOPEZ     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 2 | 2     | ADMIN   | YAÑEZ     | CARROL    | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 3 | 3     | ADMIN   | MONS      | JAFET     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 4 | 4     | USUARIO | RODRIGUEZ | LOPEZ     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 5 | 5     | USUARIO | YAÑEZ     | CARROL    | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 6 | 6     | USUARIO | MONS      | JAFET     | 20  |
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

Aquí puedes ver [la demostración y sus resultados](http://rextester.com/ZUBYJ99290).

Comment: Muchas gracias, si el detalle es que no puedo modificar la estructura de la tabla, esta funcion `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by IDSOL)` ya la estaba probando pero no sabia de que manera implementarla.

Comment: La función `ROW_NUMBER()` es una maravilla, de cualquier forma en los links que puse está la prueba de cómo puedes jugar insertando esos IDs ;)

Answer (score 2):

Podrias obtener siempre el max idsol + 1 cada vez que queres hace el insert de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @id INT 


SELECT @id = MAX(idsol) + 1 FROM #TEMP

 INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(@id,'ADMIN','RODRIGUEZ','LOPEZ',20)

 SELECT @id = MAX(idsol) + 1 FROM #TEMP

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(@id,'ADMIN','YAÑEZ','CARROL',20)

 SELECT @id = MAX(idsol) + 1 FROM #TEMP

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(@id,'ADMIN','MONS','JAFET',20)
```

De esta forma te aseguras de insertar siempre el siguiente id al ultimo generado.

Comment: +1 porque es mas completa jajaja xD

Comment: Gracias, este proceso tiene que ir en un `SP` necesitaria hacer la consulta a la tabla con el usuario que quiero duplicar, eso ya lo tengo, ahora necesito contar cuantos registros tiene la consulta y por medio de un `WHILE` insertar registro por registro incrementando la columna `IDSOL`

Comment: Creo que se volvería un poco complicado si se manejaran grandes cantidades de datos

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a lo que comentas, que no tienes la posibilidad de modificar la tabla, lo que se me ocurre es que puedes obtener el ultimo ID ingresado y aumentarlo. Asi evitas la duplicidad. Me imagino que puedes utilizar `MAX`.

```
SELECT MAX(IDSOL) FROM tu_tabla;
```

Comment: Si hago eso va a quedar `IDSOL = 4 `, solo se insertaria el primer registro y despues tendria este error :` Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint`

Comment: es que siempre debes ir aumentando en 1, cada insert que hagas!